# An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization". java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: initialization, repository, registry, sts

please help me with this: Whenever I open my STS, a pop up came as an internal error that occurred during: "Repository registry initialization". java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException message. I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the files inside the folder:

```
{yourWorkspace}\{project}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus
```

Comment: THANKS!!! In mine it was {yourWorkspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus